# How to use RBAC in Azure for user in another tenant

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, rbac, b2b, azure-security

I have some Azure Resources I would like to control access to via RBAC. This works fine for users in the same tenant, but I would also like to grant users in another tenant read access to some of my resources via RBAC?

What is the best way to do this? Do I need to first invite the guest user via B2B, and then add RBAC to the guest user?

Is there a way to do this for an Azure Group in the guest tenant -- (i.e. invite the Azure Group via B2B and then assign RBAC to the entire group)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the best way to do this? Do I need to first invite the guest
>   user via B2B, and then add RBAC to the guest user?

Yes,your thought is right. You need to invite guest users via Azure AD B2B first. Then, you can assign a Role to the guest user in Azure AD which you invited.

Example : Assign a role from a resource group to a guest user

Go to Azure portal > select the resource group > IAM > Add > select a role and select the user in Azure AD > save

[image]

> is there a way to do this for an Azure Group in the guest tenant --
>   (i.e. invite the Azure Group via B2B and then assign RBAC to the
>   entire group)?

Of course you can do it. From that above screenshot , we can see that you can select Assign access to Azure AD users, **group**, or application. Before doing this, you should already have add guest users to a group in Azure AD.

[image]

Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: HI,@Hampton Terry. If this answer is helpful to you , please mark it as answer  so that we can help more people.Thanks!